# dateutil seems to give wrong timezone

Tags: timezone, python-datetime, python-dateutil

I use `datetime` and `dateutil` to get my current UTC offset and time zone like this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from dateutil.tz import tzlocal
>>>
>>> current_time = datetime.now(tzlocal())
>>> print('Your UTC offset is {:+g}'.format(current_time.utcoffset().total_seconds()/3600))
Your UTC offset is +2
>>> print('Your time zone is {}'.format(current_time.tzname()))
Your time zone is W. Europe Daylight Time
```

The UTC offset is correct, but not the time zone. I have Central European Daylight Time; besides, Western European Daylight Time is UTC+1 so it doesn't even match with the UTC offset that is printed. So why does this code print "W. Europe Daylight Time" and not "C. Europe Daylight Time"?

Comment: On which OS are you? Getting the name of the time zone can be tricky, esp. Windows is pretty reluctant giving that away. Side note: "Central European Daylight Time" is not a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) either (in a strict sense), it specifies a UTC offset for a certain time of the year (CEST during summer / with DST, CET during winter / no DST). E.g. I'm in Germany right now, so my *time zone* is 'Europe/Berlin' and my current UTC offset is CEST / UTC+2.

Comment: I'm on Windows. So what can it be called; a "UTC offset specifier"? I think that datetime (or dateutil.tz, perhaps) would be able to detect that "W. Europe Daylight Time" cannot be correct, since it has UTC offset +1. I guess the takeaway is not to use the `tzname` method then?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [tzlocal](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal). If you need a time zone name to work with, the IANA name is the way to go. Abbreviations like CEST are fine for "human readable output" but can be a pain to work with since some of them are ambiguous.